# How to attach AmazonEC2RoleforSSM to ec2 instance in a CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to bring up multiple ec2 instances cloudformation script. I am using a shell script to loop the `aws cloudformation create-stack` command and successfully bringing up multiple instances.

Now I need to bring these instance up with the SSM Role attached. However I don't see any way of using an existing role in the script. I need to re-create the role inside the script thus:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Compact template for creating an ec2 instance for SPT

Resources:
  IAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: SPTvacmRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2RoleforSSM

  InstanceProfile1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: IAMRole

  ec2instance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      SubnetId: subnet-0da86f65478f3d30a
      KeyName: spt-lab
      ImageId: ami-00344ae218e7aae62
      InstanceType: t2.nano
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile1
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-0d3fae6860ce71c91
```

This can be executed only once, because by the time the loop executes the command for a second time, the role SPTvacmRole already exists and the stack fails.

I've already created a role from the console manually, using the AmazonEC2RoleForSSM Policy and named it EC2RoleForSSM, however when I try to reference that role by its name  `-Ref: EC2RoleForSSM` in InstanceProfile1 without creating IAMRole, it gives an error saying *Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [EC2RoleForSSM] in the Resources block of the template*

How can I use the pre-existing role EC2RoleForSSM in the script, without having to create it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include a `Ref` function as this is used for retrieving values from parameters or resources.

Instead just use the string `EC2RoleForSSM` like below.

```
  InstanceProfile1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - EC2RoleForSSM
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris for pointing out this rather silly typo.

Comment: That is no problem glad I could help out :)

Answer (score 0):

> However I don't see any way of using an existing role in the script. I need to re-create the role inside the script

> How can I use the pre-existing role EC2RoleForSSM in the script, without having to create it again?

If the role exists, you can't create the same role in CloudFormation. Instead, you should **import it**:

- [Bringing existing resources into CloudFormation management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)

`AWS::IAM::Role` is one of the resources that [can be imported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) into CloudFormation.

If you just want to reference it in the templates, @ChrisWilliams already explained how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for pointers to some rather interesting documentation. This will definitely help me.

Comment: @RameshMenon No problem. Glad the issue was solved.